# Can not use new installed packages from npm in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

In my Laravel5.4 project i just installed a package via npm.

```
npm install noty
```

[image]
.

My new noty folder is actually created in my node_modules folder. How to require the new installed package? For now i can t use it.

if i do

```
require('noty');
```

and run my code

```
noty({
        type: 'success',
        layout: 'bottomLeft',
        text: '3'
    });
```

I am still getting the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: noty is not defined
```

Regards Valentin

Comment: `require('noty');`.

Comment: yeah i know, but it won t find my installed package "noty".

Comment: Can you add the exact error you get to your question.

Comment: I edited my first post now

Comment: Where do you add this code and do you compile with mix?

Comment: Thanks that was a hint for me, i actually had a mistake in including my app.js where my bootstrap file is required.
Finally i got my problem solved

Answer (score 1):

## **I assume you have already followed the steps for [Installation](https://ned.im/noty/#/installation) the noty**

## step #1

If you did this correctly, in your laravel project a folder will be added node_modules, open search the directory noty open: `noty > lib`, copy the files noty.css and noty.js

## step #2

Paste the noty.css file in the `public > css` and the noty.js file in the `public > js` directory.

## step #3

Add this code in app.blade.php

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/noty.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="{{ asset('js/noty.min.js') }}"></script>
```

## step #4

Call Noty

```
 @if(Session::has('success'))
        new Noty({

            type: 'success',

            layout: 'topRight',

            text: 'Noty of Claud Sumbus',

        }).show();
    @endif
```

## step #5

And end.

Say something after trying